# sprintf() function, why use it?

Tags: php, mysql

I am a total noob and the idea of formatting strings is not clear to me. Why would I want to format my string like the one in the example below? Please give a short, clear answer, not like the one in the manual, I have no idea what the manual is trying to say.

```
$query=sprintf("SELECT COUNT(id) FROM users WHERE UPPER(username) = UPPER('%s')",
     mysql_real_escape_string($name));
```

Comment: You wouldn't want to use sprintf for making SQL statements. You would want to use prepared statements instead.

Comment: I dunno, the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) seem pretty clear to me.

Comment: Take a look at some of the examples on the [manual page for `sprintf`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php); that will give you some idea what it's useful for.

Comment: Because it is more readable than using string concatenation.

Comment: suppose `$name` value is `user2534840` then sprintf will return `"SELECT COUNT(id) FROM users WHERE UPPER(username) = UPPER('user2534840')"` to `$query`, its a technique to prepare SQL query dynamically

Comment: @Joni Most of the time the syntax for prepared statements is very much like `sprintf()` anyway. :P

Comment: Why would you use any function? To solve a specific problem that you have. No offence, but I don't think this is the kind of question you should be asking here so as far as I am concerned, the question should be closed.

Comment: Thanks Grijesh It is more clear to me now, I thought it is some kind of hack prevention but I guess I can write the code without sprint()

Answer (score 2):

In your particular example, you would format the string like that so you could then pass it into a mysql call that expects valid SQL. There are other ways to format the command of course, but `sprintf` allows the formatting to be more complex without adding complexity of code.

Edit: as @Joni comments, you really do *not* want to use sprintf for crafing SQL statements. This is because typically when doing this, you don't have simple control over the contents being sprintf'd into your command and this makes it too easy for an attacker to inject something you didn't expect.

Comment: So I can just delete sprintf and write it like this $query="SELECT COUNT(id) FROM users WHERE UPPER(username) = UPPER", ?

Comment: @user2534840 yes, if username don't includes any escape char.  Notice code uses `mysql_real_escape_string()` function that is important.

Answer (score 2):

Because it's way easier to read [and write] code like:

```
$query = sprintf(
  "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = %d AND name LIKE '%s' AND age > %d",
  mysql_real_escape_string($id),
  mysql_real_escape_string($name),
  mysql_real_escape_string($age)
);
```

Rather than:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = ".mysql_real_escape_string($id)
  ." AND name LIKE '".mysql_real_escape_string($name)
  ."' AND age > " . mysql_real_escape_string($age);
```

Trust me, I remember the days I spent trying to decipher wtf printf did in other peoples' code and being wholly confused. Then it just clicked one day and it feels like so much more work to do it any other way.

[Read the docs.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php)

Comment: wow that is nicer to look at, thanks for this example!

Answer (score 0):

The [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) are clear to me.

*Returns a string produced according to the formatting string format.*

It allows you to specify the the desired format. For the example you're providing, it really isn't a good way to approach this. You would want to use pdo or mysqli that supports prepared statements and the ability to bind parameters.

Comment: I tried with mysqli and it doesn't work. Prepared statements and the ability to bind parameters, what are those two?

Comment: @user2534840 Check [this](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) out. It'll help you understand.

Comment: @user2534840 [bindParam](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php) even takes a third parameter for [data types](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.constants.php)

Answer (score 0):

sprintf returns a formatted string according to the formatting string format.

Format is :

```
string sprintf ( string $format [, mixed $args [, mixed $... ]] )
```

As Here you have used '%s' in the query, after that you are giving it's value.

For example :

```
<?php
$num = 5;
$location = 'tree';

$format = 'There are %d monkeys in the %s';
echo sprintf($format, $num, $location);
?>
```

**Output : "There are 5 monkeys in the tree"**

For more understanding, refer : http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php

Answer (score 0):

Because it makes it very simple and clear what the resulting string will look like and saves you a number of explicit casts and data formatting functions. Compare:

```
echo 'Foo bar baz (' . number_format($num, 2) . ') \'quotes\''. (int)$var . ': ' . someFunction($baz);
```

vs.

```
printf("Foo bar baz (%.2f) 'quotes'%d: %s", $num, $var, someFunction($baz));
```

I don't know about you, but the first version makes my eyes bleed.